# Ubuntu 15.10 on Dell Inspiron 13-7353

Tags: hardware

I’ve installed Ubuntu 15.10 on a Dell Inspiron 13-7353.  Things work okay overall, but two critical problems have appeared.

First, occasionally, when the laptop wakes up from sleep the screen will come on and I can see the desktop, but things are frozen.  No keyboard entry or mouse cursor movement. Even the caps lock LED won’t toggle.

A second problem has popped up after the last few updates.  After waking from sleep, and using for a minute or so, the trackpad cursor freezes.  If I have a terminal window up and in focus, I can still type in commands.

Would anyone happen to have some experience or advice to resolve these issues?  I’ve tried to do an upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04, and my attempts have been unsuccessful.  The upgrade seems to make it through, but on reboot things never make it to the login screen.  I have to fire up Clonezilla and restore my 15.10 backup.

I keep the 15.10 install updated with the latest stable kernels and updates.

Are there any Dell device drivers available to try?

Is there a better/tested distribution and version of Linux to use?  I’d actually probably prefer Debian, but when I tried that disto I couldn’t get the wireless to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Dell Inspiron 1440 and everything similar to your Dell in the beginning of Ubuntu installation which came pretty handy.

First, you need available internet access which will use to download the driver given by Ubuntu. You can use USB tethering (You need smartphone with USB cable) or a modem (broadband) before you can connect to WIFI.

[Follow this instruction for Android devices](http://www.junauza.com/2012/07/how-to-tether-android-smartphone-to.html)

[Follow this instruction for iPhone devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126340/how-do-i-set-up-the-iphone-usb-ethernet-driver)

[Follow this instruction for any Modem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468691/usb-mobile-broadband-dongles-in-ubuntu-14-04-where-to-start)

After you have connected to the Internet then follow this instruction to [install Driver for Ubuntu](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/drivers)

All the given links are easy to follow and include all the screenprints.

I hope this can help other Dell Inspiron users who switch to Linux.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.